# Use sed to delete from "//" to the end of the line

Tags: bash, sed

So I feel like the title is self explanatory. I'm new to sed and am having trouble with the syntax to find multi character patterns like // and delete the pattern all the way to the end of the line. For example, I would like this

```
// here's some stuff
here's some other stuff // here's even more stuff
```

to turn into this

```
here's some other stuff
```

I've tried `sed -i -e '/\/\*/d' $FILENAME`, but that's not working.

Comment: You missed a slash. You escaped the `*` instead of a second slash.

Comment: `sed -i "s/\/\/.*$//" $FILENAME` or `sed -i "s://.*$::" $FILENAME`.

Comment: There's a lot of slashes... where did I miss one?

Comment: Remember that `sed` uses the slash by default to demark the search string, which uses two of your slashes. Also, the way you wrote your RE, it would delete the *entire line* if it found the matching string.

Answer (score 4):

You can use this sed command with alternate regex delimiter `~`:

```
sed -i.bak '\~^[[:blank:]]*//~d; s~//.*~~' file
here's some other stuff
```

`\~^[[:blank:]]*//~d` is used to delete all lines where `//` is at the start (or after some whitespaces at start).

`s~//.*~~` is used to remove text starting from `//` where `//` comes in the middle.

Answer (score 2):

```
sed -i -e 's|//.*||' -e '/^[[:space:]]*$/d' $FILENAME
```

Using the | lets you not worry about the / in your pattern. The second one just deletes any ensuing lines created that only contain zero or more spaces.

```
echo -e '// some first comment\nsome comment // here is the comment' | sed -e 's|//.*||' -e '/^[[:space:]]*$/d'
some comment
```

This isn't as neat as another answer here, but it's fairly easy to read and understand.

[updated to handle deleting blank lines]

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -i 's/\/\/[^\/\/]\+$//' $FILENAME
```

#### Edit

the above code would delete the string between the last occurrence of `//` until the end of the line.

To delete the string from the first occurrence of `//` use the following as suggested in the comments:

```
sed -i 's/\/\/.*$//' $FILENAME
```

Comment: I would use `.*` instead of `[^/]\+`: your solution won't remove the comment from this line `hello world // this is 1/2 right`. Also, you're working on the file **name** not the file **contents**

Comment: good point, but `.*` would delete the whole string from the first occurence of `//` until the end of the string right?